# How can I fit Amazon Glacier into my existing backup procedure?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

Earlier this week, Amazon announced a new service, called [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/):

> Amazon Glacier is an extremely **low-cost storage service** that provides
>   secure and **durable storage for data archiving and backup**. In order to
>   keep costs low, Amazon Glacier is optimized for data that is
>   infrequently accessed and for which retrieval times of several hours
>   are suitable. With Amazon Glacier, customers can reliably store large
>   or small amounts of data for as little as **$0.01 per gigabyte per
>   month**, a significant savings compared to on-premises solutions.

With such attractive prices, I'd like to consider using Amazon Glacier either in place of existing backup plans, or in addition to them. What should I be aware of before I start using Glacier, and how should I get started with sending my data?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your existing backup procedures...

Comment: what to be aware of ? It gets real expensive to pull all the data out in one go.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you can look for the answer in amazon site in http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/#importexport

After you import the data then you can use amazon API to create vaults for continuous backup

Comment: Amazon simply says you *can* do this (they support using the product in this way) - That page is very light on the **how**. Can you update your answer to provide more practical details on implementing this -- perhaps an example with a specific backup tool?